# Java SWT: tab \t doesnt work in lists

Tags: java, swt

im having some trouble with the List class in Java SWT:

if I write

```
list.add("1\t2")
```

the list shows:

```
12
```

But of course it should show a tab between the 1 and 2.

Also it doesnt work if I write a "real" tab between 1 and 2. Somewhow it just gets deleted.

So how can i make a tab in lists? The documentation says: "Note: If control characters like '\n', '\t' etc. are used in the string, then the behavior is platform dependent. " This doesnt really help me :/ I'm using Windows 7

btw \n also doesnt work.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: If you want multiple columns you need to use `Table`, you won't get this to work reliably with `List`.

Comment: That is a great idea. Thanks :)